# Is there a way to get more horizontal coverage out of "Vase Mode" in Simplify3D?

Tags: print-quality, simplify3d

I like using "Vase Mode" (or single outline corkscrew printing mode) for quick nonfunctional prints, but it tends to leave gaps in horizontal or near horizontal surfaces. I understand why it does this, but is there a way (beyond printing with no infill*) to get a little more horizontal coverage out of it?

*Is the answer to this literally just "Try to print without infill?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 4 allows you to have multi-process vase mode prints -- do the vertical surfaces in vase mode, then switch over to normal mode for the horizontals. This lets you have the best of both worlds in the same print. :)

Answer (score 1):

Vase mode is what it is... As it prints one perimeter there is just one extrusion. Try increasing extrusion rate to see if that will fix the gaps.

but yes, printing without infill will do the job better than vase mode.